# heroku uninitialized constant Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've seen some issues posted like this but any answer solve my problem :(

I'm trying to deploy my application to heroku, I have used devise for a simple authentication, al the deploy seems to rum ok but when I browse to my app I see the error:

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

I've tryed to run heroku rake db:migrate but I'm still getting the same error.

Thanks in advance,
My log is:

```
2012-08-27T21:23:17+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick 2012-08-27T21:23:17+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in pro duction on http://0.0.0.0:17074 2012-08-27T21:23:17+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach 2012-08-27T21:23:17+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server 2012-08-27T21:23:17+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABA SE_URL 2012-08-27T21:23:21+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting 2012-08-27T21:23:21+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/admin_user/omniauth_c allbacks_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant AdminUser s (NameError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb you should change all instances of the constant "AdminUsers" to "AdminUser" (no 's' at the end).

Comment: When querying any database (in this case the AdminUsers database) always use the singular version of the database name. :) http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html